# Given a neural network and a problem size N, 2N, 3N... How would the space complexity of the network scale with the problem size?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, space-complexity

Given a neural network and a problem size N, 2N, 3N... Generally speaking, how would the space complexity (i.e., the number of parameters) of the network scale with the problem size? Linearly? Polynomially? Exponentially?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more details. What is your NN? What is your problem? How do you measure it's size? E.g. most NLP architectures, be they recurrent or attention based, are constant size wrt. length or your document. However as you them expand during the forward pass, they do scale with the problem.

Comment: This is a research question, not a programming one, so it is off-topic.